# DenseBase, auto, and binary operation says arrays have different shape

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I write a function that takes two `DenseBase` as arguments.

The function uses `.derived().array()` to convert both `Array` and `Matrix` to `Array`.

I got tired of writing `derived` for many times and use auto.

But `auto` leads to strange error. Eigen complains that `x2` and `y2` don't have same shape.

If I don't want to write `.derived().array()` for many times, what can I use?

Eigen is from https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror.git

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
int main() {
    Eigen::ArrayXf x(3);
    Eigen::ArrayXf y(3);
    x << 1, 2, 3;
    y << 4, 5, 6;
    // x.derived().array() * y.derived().array();
    auto x2 = x.derived().array();
    auto y2 = y.derived().array();
    y2 = x2 * y2; 
}
```

Run time error:

```
CwiseBinaryOp.h:110: ...

Assertion `aLhs.rows() == aRhs.rows() 
           && aLhs.cols() == aRhs.cols()' failed.
```

Comment: Generally, avoid `auto` with Eigen expressions, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: I see two options. 1. use lots of `.derived().array()` within the function. 2. Use `ArrayBase` instead of `DenseBase`. Make a function `void f(ArrayBase<D>& x) {}`. To call the function, use `auto s = big_mat.array(); f(s);` where `big_mat` is a matrix instead of an array. Would option 2 avoid copying the big matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the runtime issue with `auto x2 = x.array().derived();`, that is: reverse array and derived. But `auto` is not desirable here. Here is why. Say you have:

```
template <typename T> void foo(DenseBase<T> &x);
```

If `T` is an `Array<>` then `x.array().derived()` is an `Array<>` and `x2` will be a deep copy of `x`. In this case you would like to use `auto& x2 = ...`.

If `T` is something else, e.g., a `Matrix<>`, then `auto x2 = x.array().derived();` is perfectly fine, but not `auto& x2 = ...`.

So what you really want is something as complicated as:

```
internal::ref_selector<std::decay<decltype(x.array().derived())>::type>::non_const_type
  x2 = x.array().derived();
```

Not nice :(

A simpler solution is to not bother and create an `ArrayWrapper` even for inputs that are already in the array world:

```
ArrayWrapper<T> x2(x.derived());
```

Yet another simple solution is to enforce the caller to pass expressions in the array world:

```
template <typename T> void foo(ArrayBase<T> &x) {
  T& x2(x.derived());
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would the `ArrayWrapper` hurt performance in any possible way?

Comment: No impact on runtime, only slightly on compilation time because you create new types, but that's marginal.