# Can't construct ArrayWrapper from const DenseBase

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I used `ArrayWrapper` to convert both array and matrix to array.

Use case: [DenseBase, auto, and binary operation says arrays have different shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324127/densebase-auto-and-binary-operation-says-arrays-have-different-shape)

Problem: can't construct `ArrayWrapper<D>` with `const` `DenseBase<D>`.

Test (also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'//+Type+your+code+here,+or+load+an+example.%0A%23include+%3CEigen/Eigen%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+D%3E%0Avoid+f(const+Eigen::DenseBase%3CD%3E%26+arr)+%7B%0A++++const+Eigen::ArrayWrapper%3CD%3E+wrapper(arr)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++Eigen::ArrayXXf+a(3,+4)%3B%0A++++f(a)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4))

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

template <typename D>
void f(const Eigen::DenseBase<D>& arr) {
    const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<D> wrapper(arr);
}

int main() {
    Eigen::ArrayXXf a(3, 4);
    f(a);
}
```

Comment: `const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<const D> wrapper(arr);` seems to work. But would that cause any potential problem?

Comment: You got the right solution. Since `arr` is const you can only construct a const wrapper: `ArrayWrapper<const D>`. This is what `arr.array()` would return if `D` is not already in the array world.